# Use cygwin to run a batch file and email results

Tags: email, batch-file, cmd, cygwin, scheduled-tasks

I am new to using cygwin and don't really understand how the scripting of it works. Currently I am running it on Windows 7 and using task scheduler to do this inefficiently.

What I want to do is to run a .bat file already made that runs tests in the cmd line and than take the results of that test and email that people.

Some side notes:
1. It doesn't HAVE to be a batch file, from my reading I think maybe a .sh would be easier to run with bash. Being able to run it on CentOS would be even better, that way others can run if I leave.
2. This needs to run daily. I would like to run the batch file at around 10 am and give it an hour till the emailed results are sent, unless you can trigger the email when the .bat is done.
3. Every time I run this .bat file it saves the results to a .htm file and overwrites it every time the .bat is run.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That could be in the crontab for a a centOS server  (/etc/crontab)

> 0 10    * * *   user    cd /path/ && /bin/bash file.sh >> result_file

Is that what you needed ? Also, you can install Cron as a windows service with cygrunsrv

Comment: Is crontab usually already on Cent OS (6.5) and im not sure what that command does.

Comment: I dont think it comes with a default install. In that case, just install it with `yum install cronie`

Comment: Alright. Do you mind explaining a little how your code works/ do I need to change the batch file to .sh and put them in centos somewhere?

Comment: The line i wrote is supposed to be inserted into /etc/crontab after you installed cron. You will find some info here http://alvinalexander.com/linux/linux-crontab-file-format-example The ">> result_file" means that any standard output from your script will be added to the result_file. Your script can have any name, any extension. Usually, prefer .sh extension to show that its a shell script. You can put the file anywhere on your centos and then, refer to it from your crontab to make it run periodically.